# OpenCV - Accessing the cv2.findContours variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pycharm, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCv 3.0 with Python 2.7, for Optical Character Recognition I need to find points of each contours that are found by findContours method. When I do debugging, I can see there are 208 countours found but I am curious about how can I access them.

Here is the method for capturing contours:

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I need something like this:

```
cv2.getcontoursPoints(contour)
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have your contours point in **`contours`** output which is a **python list composed of Numpy array of `(x,y)` coordinates**.  Take care that as said in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) you have several contours layers :

> Each contour [of `countours`] is stored as a vector of points.

So if you print `contours[0]` it will display a list of points. So if you want to access precisely a point in a specific layer you have to detail an index again.

Comment: I don't want to draw them. I need the coordinate values of every single points (as int, double or float) to teach letters to my machine. I am going to use those values in machine learning algoritm.

Comment: Well as said in the answeryou have the coordinates values already in `contours` ... What is bothering you in that ?

Comment: i.e. at the first contour I have the values of [[[532 229]] [[536 229]] [[539 232]] [[539 233]] [[540 234]] [[540 238]] [[539 239]] [[539 240]] [[536 243]] [[532 243]] [[528 239]] [[528 234]] [[529 233]] [[529 232]]] – I neet to get these numbers by using some spesific method.

Comment: I don't understand what you want... You are answering yourself you have these values right under your eyes... What is your aim ? What do you want to do with these values ? Reformulate your question please

Comment: Exactly they are just in front of my eyes, but I can't get these values in my program. drawContours is for drawing; however I am targeting to have specific contour's array (as numbers). For instance, how can I get the values of 45th contour as `45th_contour = contour(45)`. When I  `print 45th_contour` it will output this : _[[344 179]]
[[345 178]]
[[348 178]] ..._

Comment: You are printing there the nth contours which hold many points. You have to specify again an index to get the point you want. I ll detail this.

Comment: Thanks in advance, would be nice. This was what I am asking for.

Comment: I detailed my answer `contour[layer][idx]` where layer and idx are integers should give you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`for cnt in contours:
    print(cnt)`

you will be able to see numpy array of all the contours.